# Retrieve time portion of date

Tags: java, date, time

How can I retrieve the time portion of a date?

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat(date));
```

Comment: What now? Would you care to expand on that question?

Comment: Your problem isnt very clear to me. please try to add another sentence :p

Comment: get a new date and get time of this date like HH:mm:ss

Comment: hello, i want time to recover from a date.
sorry, but it isnt getting much clearer

Comment: Best-guess fixed your question, hope you get some answers now.

Comment: I want to do this get a date like this :2008/05/19 10:25:00
and get just the time : 10:25:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = dateFormat.format(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't believe:

```
String result = dateFormat.format(date);
```